# Pandas group by, sum greater than and count

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have a dataframe with "day", "month", "type" and "value". I want to group by "day", "month" and "type", and then sum and count "value". However I only want the sum to consider "value">15.
What I have right now is:

```
final = test.groupby(['DAY','MONTH','TYPE']).VALUE.aggregate(['sum','count'])
```

Which returns almost exactly what I want, except it sums all values. How can I make it so the sum will only consider values greater than 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for create new column filled by `NaN`s for values `<= 15` by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html), then is used named aggregation:

```
final = (test.assign(new = test['VALUE'].where(test['VALUE'] > 15))
             .groupby(['DAY','MONTH','TYPE'])
             .aggregate(sum = ('new', 'sum'),
                        count = ('VALUE', 'count')))
```

Comment: @CarlV.Bresser - I think missing last `)`, can you try?